# CSS Mobile Footer Navigation

Tags: css

At https://www.sfwatertaxi.net, any suggestions why the spacing underneath the footer navigation items is disproportionately large on mobile devices?

Below is the code used to create footer navigation columns on mobile.

```
ul.nav {
    column-count: 3;
    display: inline-block;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just inspected your footer CSS code and found out that you have this code:

```css
@media (max-width: 767px)
.gh-foot {
    padding-bottom: 160px;
    padding-top: 64px;
}
```

Maybe it's because of a custom library component.

To **FIX IT**, you can add something like this to your code:

```css
.gh-foot {
    padding-bottom: 90px !Important;
}
```

If you want to manage the spacing just on mobile, you can use this instead:

```css
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .gh-foot {
        padding-bottom: 90px !Important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried changing the padding-bottom to 32px and there is no difference.

Comment: Check with "inspect element" if your padding is being applied, because the problem is clearly that `padding-bottom: 160px` inside `.gh-foot`. You should find the way to override it.